# Jquery this.src is blank

Tags: jquery, src

I am trying to retrieve the src attribute from an href. I have tried various methods including:

```
this.src
$(this).data('src');
$("#"+tid).src; <!-- tid is the variable that holds the id of the tag -->
```

Other than returning a blank value for src, the function works as expected and the var tid is correctly populated with the id. Once I can get the src, I will toggle between an up and down arrow when clicked.

Here is my latest attempt:
Jquery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".toggle").click(getData);
});

function getData()
{ 
  var tid = (this.id);
  alert(tid); 
 var isrc = (this.src)
 alert(isrc);
$("#"+tid+"1").toggle();  
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="jqxWidget">
<a id="jqxgrid" class = "toggle" href="#;" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 2px 10px;"><img src="img/arrowdown.gif"></a>
<div id="jqxgrid1"></div>
</div>
```

I have stared at this long and would appreciate a fresh set of eyes looking at it.

Thanks,

Len

Comment: Are you trying to get the image's `src`? Because `this`, in a click handler for the `<a>` tag, will be the `<a>`, not the `img`.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the image that is associated with the<a> tag
<a id="jqxgrid" class = "toggle" href="#;" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 2px 10px;"><img src="img/arrowdown.gif"></a>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the `img` src:

```
var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
```

Your click handler is on the `a` - which has an `img` child.

Answer (score 1):

to get the `src` attribute, use `.attr()`

```
$('#' + tid).attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an *attribute*, use jQuery's `attr` method ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)): `$(myThing).attr("src")`

Note that jQuery has an example in the docs that uses `src`; however, they are setting the `src` attribute rather than retrieving it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>attr demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img title="hat.gif">

<script>
$( "img" ).attr( "src", function() {
  return "/resources/" + this.title;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var src = $('#jqxWidget').find(img).attr('src');
```

Take a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4tu9/) to check it in the console